# AngularJS controller not update model from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular, but i do not understand why controller updates data from service only in some cases ...
http://plnkr.co/edit/pV8m11Bc1vItDSmQKECS?p=preview
object1 and 2 are correctly updated, but objet3 is not.
Seems that Service.get3() is just fired once. 
I understand that Angular watch for object changes, fine for object1 and object2 (that is a reference to object1) by the way, it's great.
But it's not working with object3 ... ok it's not a reference...
The question is : how to build new objects in service ?

Thank you,
Philippe

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.factory('Service', [

  function() {
    var object1 = ["TOTO"];
    return {
      get1: function() {
        return object1;
      },
      get2: function() {
        var object2 = object1;
        return object2;
      },
      get3: function() {
        var object3 = [];
        /*
                object1.forEach(function(entry) {
                    object3.push(entry);
                    console.log(entry);
                });
                */

        for (i = 0; i < object1.length; i++) {
          object3.push(object1[i]);
        }

        return object3;
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        object1.push(newValue);
      }
    }
  }
]);

app.controller('Controller', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Service',
  function($rootScope, $scope, Service) {

    $scope.object1 = Service.get1();
    $scope.object2 = Service.get2();
    $scope.object3 = Service.get3();

    $scope.set = function() {
      Service.set("TITI");
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned the third object is a different array.  In order to have it notify your controller of changes you'll probably want to register a watch on it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EdXVKqe5eaZgROFDG9U9?p=preview

```
$scope.$watch(Service.get3, function(val) {
   $scope.object3 = Service.get3();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. $watch from controllers to see updates from services is a workaround or is the right way to share new data ? I know the best is to shared references, but it's not always possible.

Comment: Watches are an integral part of angular.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are bound to object1. The third is bound to a different array altogether.